# Android: unknown xml attributes after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-xml, android-studio-2.0

Recently I've updated the Android Studio up to the version 2.0. Also I've updated build gradle tools to the 2.0.0. After that many warnings like "Unknown attrubute..." appeared in my xml layout files. However preview screen displays layout files correctly and the studio still builds the project without any problems. But almost all xml attributes are higlighted as warnings and auto-complete doesn't work. I've tried to return gradle tools version to the 1.5.0 and decrease target SDK version, but it hasn't helped. Please can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Here is screenshot of one of the xml layout files: https://yadi.sk/i/lD6G0ylnr2EjX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was a temporary glitch. Now no warnings more.